# D3 linear scale between two numbers

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts

I would like to generete scale with d3 (v7) between 180 and 360 (inclusive) with 4 ticks. Actually i need a scale with values/ticks: 180, 240, 300 and 360.

I tired this:

```
d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([180, 360]).ticks(4)
```

but I get:

```
[200, 250, 300, 350]
```

Does anyone know how to generate scale to get ticks mentioned above `[180, 240, 300, 360]`

**EDITED**

I try to generate scale/axis for some chart:

```
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([180, 360])
      .range([containerHeight, 0]);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
      .ticks(4);

svg.append('g')
      .call(yAxis);
```

As you can see the scale in axis is wrong. Instead of 180, 240, 300 and 300 I get 200, 250, 300 and 350

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want an array with values given a start, end and count, you don't need d3 for that.

```js
const ticks = 4;
const start = 180;
const end = 360;

console.log(Array.from({length: ticks}, (_, i) => i *  (end - start) / (ticks - 1) + start))
```

This creates the array [180, 240, 300, 360] so just plug that in instead of the d3 code as I've done below via tickValues...

```js
let svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 300)
                .attr("height", 150);
                
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([180, 360])
      .range([100, 0]);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
      .tickValues(Array.from({length: 4}, (_, i) => i *  60 + 180));

svg.append('g').attr("transform", "translate(50,10)")
      .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need d3. This code is part of chart. I am creating line chart with specific yAxis.

Comment: @user3714967: as a reminder: please **be respectful** to all SO users answering your questions! The best approach to avoid misunderstandings is to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Often questions about frameworks/libraries are based on a lack of understanding of the basic principles of the concepts/technologies involved (e.g. bootstrap, tailwind, d3 etc.).
Please fetch up with other OPs that have managed to include working snippets (including  cdn hosted d3.js). Your chances of getting an expert opinion will skyrocket.

Comment: I tought scale should generate right numbers but setting tick values on axis is also an option 